# Deserialize JSON with dynamic keys using C# Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

From an external API I am receiving the below JSON response for the bank details of a customer.

```
{
   "bankDetails":[
      {
         "ABC Bank":[
            {
               "sNo":1,
               "acNo":"1235465",
               "acBalance":"100.25"
            },
            {
               "sNo":2,
               "acNo":"1235467",
               "acBalance":"50.25"
            }
         ],
         "bankName":"ABC Bank",
         "totalAmount":"150.50"
      },
      {
         "XYZ Bank":[
            {
               "sNo":1,
               "acNo":"1248565",
               "acBalance":"75.25"
            }
         ],
         "bankName":"XYZ Bank",
         "totalAmount":"75.25"
      },
      {
         "BCD Bank":[
            {
               "sNo":1,
               "acNo":"145665",
               "acBalance":"10.25"
            },
            {
               "sNo":2,
               "acNo":"195267",
               "acBalance":"5.25"
            }
         ],
         "bankName":"BCD Bank",
         "totalAmount":"15.50"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to deserialize this to a C# class using JSON.Net. What should be structure of the C# class as the first key is dynamic?. The first key with bank name returned will be different for each customer

Comment: Can you clarify "different bank details"?

Comment: Instead of ABC, BCD, XYZ Banks it could be any other bank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical solution to dealing with dynamic keys is to use a `Dictionary<string, T>` in place of a regular class.  See [How can I deserialize a child object with dynamic (numeric) key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24771804/10263) for an example of this.  However, that solution doesn't really work for your case, because there are other properties in the same object which do not have dynamic keys (the `bankName` and `totalAmount`), and the values of those properties are primitives whereas the value of dynamic property is an array of bank accounts.  A better solution here is to use a [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).

Before we get to that, we need to set up a class structure to deserialize into.  This is pretty straightforward:

```
class RootObject
{
    public List<Bank> BankDetails { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(BankConverter))]
class Bank
{
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

class Account
{
    [JsonProperty("sNo")]
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("acNo")]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("acBalance")]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

You'll notice that I've added a few `[JsonProperty]` attributes in the `Account` class to map the shorthand property names in the JSON to friendlier property names in that class.  And the `[JsonConverter]` attribute on the `Bank` class tells the serializer that we will be using a custom `BankConverter` to handle that class.

Here is the code for the `BankConverter`.  It uses a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) internally to make it easier to read and work with the JSON.

```
class BankConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Bank);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        Bank bank = new Bank();
        // populate the known properties (bankName and totalAmount)
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), bank);
        // now handle the dynamic key
        bank.Accounts = obj[bank.BankName].ToObject<List<Account>>(serializer);
        return bank;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

With these classes in place, you can deserialize the JSON like this:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/knsRLv